# Z-index of google charts and other elements on page

Tags: html, css, charts

I have a page with several Google Charts on it. And I have a CSS hover dropdown legend that stays at the top of the screen. But the problem is that the Google Charts appear on top of the dropdown. I have set the z-index of the dropdown div's very high. I have also used Javascript to do an innerHTML after the page loads so that the dropdown is created after the charts. It does the same thing if I create the dropdown first as well.

I don't understand if this is something within the Google Charts that is taking precedence, or if there is some "order of operations" I'm not aware of. I'm not a seasoned veteran at this.

You can see I set the z-index for the dropdown really high. I then set the z-index of the div containers for the Google Chart to be high negative number. I tried both div's, but neither mattered.

I've included relevant HTML, any insight would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure it's something simple, I'm just not versed in this.

[image: Picture of Google Chart Z issue]

```
<head>
<style>
    .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 350px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px;
        top: -5px;
        left: 90%;

        /* Position the tooltip */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2147483640;
    }

    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
    }


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    font-size:12px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2147483647;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="legend" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;">

</div>
<br>
<div style="width: 920px; height: 600px; margin: auto; border: 2px solid #a3c3f7; border-radius: 20px;padding:20px;  z-index: -100000;">
    <div id="C05" style="width: 900px; height: 570px; margin: auto;"></div>
</div>
<script>
        document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = "<div class=\"dropdown\""><b>LPT LEGEND</b><div class=\"dropdown-content\"><p>0100blahblahblah</p></div></div>";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting the `z-index` of the `div#legend` not the dropdown contained inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @zgood !

I didn't think about the div container of the legend itself.

```
<div id="legend" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 10;">
```

Fixed it right up!